# Triangulation with Single Tone FM TX and Three RX using Phase Detection

Tags: integrated-circuit, frequency-modulation, phase, detector

I'm looking for some IC and frequency suggestions to accomplish the following task.

Modulate a tone onto a carrier and continuously broadcast this signal toward an array of three receiving antennas(ABC).  To then demodulate the tone from the carrier and generate a dc voltage through a phase comparison between each RX(AB, AC, BC).

I plan to pass these voltages through ADC's into my controller so that I can crunch the data and determine the relative location of the TX to the three RX's.

My fellow students and I are pretty solid on the programming side of things and we've each done well in our undergrad Communication Systems and RF Circuits classes but we're getting a bit lost in the actual realization of the circuit given the plethora of IC choices on the market.

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

P.S.  The RX's (ABC) will be arranged in a triangle each approximately one wavelength(of whichever freq. is decided upon) apart.  TX to RX range from .5 to 40meters.

P.S.S.  We're also open to reading suggestions either web-based or a book that get into actual component and circuit topology material.  We're full of theory but short on the real.

Comment: Demodulating the tone is missing the point for triangulation. You should be looking at the phases of the carrier - they will carry much more accurate information.

Comment: I agree with Andy, although it depends on what distances you're talking about. What distances are you talking about? You may have no choice but to build it with discrete components.

Comment: TX to RX will vary from 0.5meters to 40meters.

Comment: Although you describe three phase comparisons AB AC BC that gives only two independent variables. They can at best indicate the arrival direction in the plane of the receiving antennas but they cannot identify the *location* of the source, apart from inexactly estimating from signal strength. You also have ambiguity of sources 180 degrees apart.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of FM demodulator ICs. Which one you'll need will depend on a number of factors. Use a mono audio demodulator for large distances, use a video demodulator for medium distances, or forgo demodulation entirely (and simply use discrete components) for short distances. For high accuracy long distances, perhaps use some combination.

Example ICs:

- Video FM demodulator IC: LA72912V
- Audio FM demodulator IC: LA72914V

(Found using a simple Google search: "FM Demodulator ICs".)

Then use an appropriate ADC to get the signal for determining phase.

As an aside, you might want to use something other than a sinusoidal signal; perhaps a triangle wave or several superimposed waveforms or whatever.

Very interesting project by the way! I'd be very interested to know what you come up with.

Edit:

With distances of approximately just one wavelength, that is about as difficult as it could get. My thoughts:

- I imagine you will not find an IC that can help you.
- On the one hand, the phase of the FM signal alone will not give you the information needed to ascertain distance greater than one wavelength. On the other hand, you will have trouble modulating a signal with enough bandwidth that will give you the resolution of distances in the order of a few wavelengths. It would be a very specialist IC, and I cannot think off the top of my head what sort of applications such ICs would have. I know little about GPS, but perhaps that's something to explore.

Comment: Ahh!  I see what you are getting at.  Assuming the array is on the ground at my feet and I'm holding the transmitter above it in my hand...The design as theorized would only discover where the TX was in relation to the RX on the 2D plane of the floor.  There would be no Z or vertical information, ie distance ascertained.  Am I getting that right?  And also thank you for your input on this!

Comment: Correct. (Although that's not what I was talking about!) Are you restricted to what frequency you can use? Do you have a frequency (range) in mind?

Comment: Because the array will need to be moved from our lab building out into a field for testing...And we were going to separate the RX's by a wavelength.  We decided that the "free" for use bands, 433M, 915M, and 2.4G, would be possible candidates.